# Azure DevOps Release Pipelines have stopped not being able to download Artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-pipelines

Our release pipelines stopped working as of this morning can no longer download Artifacts that were produced by the related build pipeline.

```
2021-06-21T05:42:23.2924212Z ##[section]Starting: Download artifact - _Dev
2021-06-21T05:42:24.1919023Z ==============================================================================
2021-06-21T05:42:24.1920480Z Task         : Download build artifacts
2021-06-21T05:42:24.1921432Z Description  : Download files that were saved as artifacts of a completed build
2021-06-21T05:42:24.1923297Z Version      : 1.189.0
2021-06-21T05:42:24.1924185Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-06-21T05:42:24.1925170Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts
2021-06-21T05:42:24.1927176Z ==============================================================================
2021-06-21T05:42:24.2958112Z ##[error]Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'DownloadBuildArtifacts (a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb/1.189.0)')
```

The same build artifacts is gets download for other staged like **dev** in same release pipeline, but not working with **QA** stage.
What value cannot be null?
there is a built artifact there in the system I can see it and the release has a valid link to it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by upgrading the version from 1.189.0 to 2.0.0
After upgrading the version if you still face the issue
try this

1. Open **Download Pipeline Artifact**
2. check the **Destination Directory** property
3. If it is reset to **$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)** change to the specific path which is given by you.
4. If not check if there is any data that should be cleared in the artifact directory folder.
   Because the artifact directory should be empty before downloading.

[image]

You could refer the [Thread](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-devops-release-piplines-failing-to/551307#T-N553995) which discussed on the similar related issue.

if you are using Self hosted agents refer the [Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#to-update-self-hosted-agents) to make changes